# Elasticsearch : match query with empty string as a value for field

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a match query that query the fields `title1`, `title2`  with `param` that contains sometimes an empty string.

When the value of the `param` is empty the query returns no results which is normal.

My question is if it possible to make in one single query , this :
if the `param`  is not an empty string query all documents, otherwise do a normal multi_match query .

The pseudo code of my query:

```
{
 "query" : {
     "bool" : {
       "must" : {
          "multi_match" : {
                "query":    param, 
                "fields": [ "title1", "title2" ] 
              },
           "match" : {
                 "query": { "publish" : true}
            }

      }
    }
  }
}
```

Thanks,

Comment: I don't understand: if the query parameter has an empty value then return all documents? Can you post your query?

Comment: Sounds like something you should handle in the application creating the query. If empty string -> match_all query else match query. Using bool query together with missing filter might help you as well. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22635404/elasticsearch-match-string-or-empty-value

Comment: @AndreiStefan i edited the question with more details. in fact if the param is an empty string return all document of a match or multimach query.

Comment: @JettroCoenradie it could be done outside  the querying but i could not afford it. I must have only one query.

Comment: @JettroCoenradie i have seen the link. Actually, it's done with filters but i realy need to make in a query.

Comment: That's not possible. You need to make the decision in your application level. The link provided earlier is for missing value in the document itself, not in the search value.

Comment: @AndreiStefan Not possible to make it in a query?

Comment: My opinion is that _this is not possible_, not in a query and not in a filter.

Comment: The link from @JettroCoenradie talks about using a `missing` but that's for what is already indexed, is not for what you pass in a query. What you pass in a query is your concern and your application's concern.

Comment: Yes, i have seen that it's about missing value in the indexed document.

Comment: @AndreiStefan Could it be done via a script filter with a match all query and filter script checking if the passed param is not null will filter otherwise do nothing? or with a wildcard query pass the param if empty string replace it with *

Comment: Don't think so. A script filter can look at one parameter that you pass to it. If the parameter is null or is empty string then return true and the document is returned. Ok. Good so far. But what do you do when the parameter doesn't have an empty string? What do you return from the script? If you return `false` the document is ignored.

Comment: if param is an emtpy string return true to have a match all

Comment: Yes, this is what I said in my comment. The open question was "**But what do you do when the parameter doesn't have an empty string? What do you return from the script? If you return false the document is ignored.**"

Comment: It would be something like this : `if  (param.equals('') return true; else return  (doc['field1'].value.toLowerCase().contains(param.toLowerCase())` but i think this will have an impact on performance

Comment: :-) in this way you are not using Elasticsearch (and the underlying Lucene instances) for searching, it's just a `contains` from Java.

Answer (score 0):

If you add this parameter the problem will be solved

Return all if query is empty => "zero_terms_query": "all"

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-match-query.html

```
GET /_search
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "message": {
        "query": "",
        "zero_terms_query": "all"
      }
    }
  }
}
```