# Elasticsearch multi-match not returning all results when providing empty string

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack, elasticsearch-dsl

I have a total of 1783 records and I want ES to return all of them in case the **multi_match** query is not provided (`searchObject.query = ''`)

I manage to do so if I pass an empty array to query.bool.**should**, so in theory I could update the ES object below based on the `searchObject.query` value but I'm not sure if that's a good idea.

```
{
    _source: [
        'id',
        'event',
        'description',
        'element',
        'date'
    ],
    track_total_hits: true,
    query: {
        bool: {
            should: [{
                multi_match:{
                    query: searchObject.query
                    fields: ["element","description","nar.*","title","identifier"]
                }
            }],
            filter: []
        }
    },
    highlight: { fields: { '*': {} } },
    sort: [],
    from: 0,
    size: 10
}
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

This is regulated by [Match query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-match-query.html) `zero_terms_query` property. Just add this property to your multi_match block: `"zero_terms_query": "all"`.

Answer (score 0):

You can append a [`match_all`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-match-all-query.html) to the `should`:

```
{
  "_source": [
    "id",
    "event",
    "description",
    "element",
    "date"
  ],
  "track_total_hits": true,
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "multi_match": {
            "query": "",
            "fields": [
              "line",
              "element",
              "description",
              "nar.*",
              "title",
              "identifier"
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "match_all": {}
        }
      ],
      "filter": []
    }
  },
  "highlight": {
    "fields": {
      "*": {}
    }
  },
  "sort": [],
  "from": 0,
  "size": 10
}
```

That's what it's usually for. IMHO the empty string should be checked *before* you perform the ES request. I'm assuming it's coming from an autocomplete or such.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Indeed, the query string comes from an input and I'm still not sure how does this work if the user actually types something?

Comment: OK in that case you should decide in the frontend which query you send. Check the conversation here too: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30697557/elasticsearch-match-query-with-empty-string-as-a-value-for-field

Comment: I checked that link and his question is quite similar to mine, except I want to return all documents if the query param is not provided, otherwise do a normal multi_match query. Can I built the bool object based on the query param and then pass it to ES? I'm thinking to use match_all in case query param is empty, otherwise use multi_match as I normally do

Comment: nope there are no conditions like that. Build the query before...

Comment: How am I supposed to built the query before if I'm not using such conditions? I still need multi_match object if the query param is not empty and I still need match_all object to return all records.

Comment: You can check the string length, can’t you?

Comment: That I can :)) But I don't know how to return all the records in case query param is not provided. Simply not providing 'should' array would be enough?

Comment: yes. Empty `should`, `filter`, or `must` would do the trick. Or simply `query: match_all: {}`, like above.